# How to resolve issue on two aws accounts with resepctive VPCs on the same subnet range to talk to each others

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, vpc, private-subnet

We have two AWS accounts:

Account A have a VPC with 172.31.21.0/16 subnet.

Account B have 3 VPCs:
VPC 1 : 172.31.0.0/16 Default
VPC 2 : 172.32.0.0/16
VPC 3 : 172.30.0.0/16

We have an EC2 on Account A's VPC, that needs to talk to RDS(MySQL) on Account B's VPC 2 but I cannot connect the RDS from EC2 on Account A.

Is the problem caused by Account B's VPC 1 which is using the same subnet as Account A's VPC?

If so, how can we resolve the issue?

Comment: `Account A have a VPC with 172.31.21.0/16 subnet.`. That is not a valid CIDR, pleace check and correct as it may affect the answer.

Comment: thanks. the impact is huge if I were to change the IP range, thus status quo but the solution for me is to make RDS publicly available and access via public IP.

Comment: What I meant is that you probably made a typing error in your question

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 172.31.21.0/16 or 172.31.21.0/24? Having the first scenario is useless. Did you set up the VPC peering connection and tried to add routes? I believe you will have problem with network range overlapping. Also VPC peering connection will work if you're using the same region in both accounts.

Comment: thanks for the tips. the solution is to make RDS publicly available then I can access via public IP instead.

Comment: I hope that's your decision to make database publicly available only temporary one. Database should be in private subnet. At least update security group rule end expose database only for needed IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

presumably you already have a peering connection ( a pcx ) for A -> B

So either

1) alter the addressing on Account B VPC 1 so that it doesn't overlap with Account A VPC

2) add an explict route for Account B VPC 2 route table sending 172.31.21.0/16 to the pcx.  But in this case routing to Account B VPC1 from VPC2 will be broken for some addresses

Answer (score 0):

If only 1 server connection is required, you can setup a EC2 instance and attach to EIP. Then use that EC2 as SSH tunnel that connect to the RDS.  Then another VPC can connect to the EC2 secure tunnel.

(Background info)

VPC are virtually isolated, Even within the same AWS account.

Connecting VPC A to VPC B is NOT POSSIBLE, unless you 
i. Setup AWS VPC PEER.  or 
ii. assign EIP to the resource you want to connect, then everyone connect through the public IP, or 
iii. Create some sort of VPN routing.

However, in case of i,iii because both your account A and B using 172.31.X.X/16,  VPC peering will NOT works, even VPN setup will failed due to same IP network subnet used. 
Nevertheless, you may use NAT to share particular resources using VPN, but it will be a "limited VPN".

In addition, you cannot use AWS NAT gateway features for NAT, because that services is only mean for NAT connection from VPC private network to internet.

You can checkout AWS this [link for example of multiple VPC peer connection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/peering-configurations-partial-access.html#multiple-configurations).

Comment: thanks for the tips. it is resolved now by making rds publicly available